# How to add a subkey in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested, nested-lists

So i have a list of typles:
x= [('0', '0', '20'), ('0', '0', '25'),('0', '3', '28'), ('1', '1', '74'), ('1', '1', '2')]

I want to create a nested dictionary by iterating the original (not addding them manually) to get:

dictionary= {'0': {'0': ('20', '25')},{'3': ('28')} , '1': {'1': ('74', '2')}}

In other words, in the list of tuples, group them by: the first element of the tuples being the key, the second the subkey and the third the value of the subkey.

- If two tuples have the same key and subkey we add the value to the values (i.e.{'0':'0': ('20', '25')}
- If they have the same key but different subkey, we add a subkey,key pair under the same key (i.e.{'0':{'0': ('20', '25')},{'3': ('28')}}

How would the code be?

Comment: Is `'0': {'0': ('20', '25')},{'3': ('28')}` correct? What you want is `'0': { '0': ('20', '25'), '3': ('28') }`, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
x = [('0','0','20'),('0','0','25'),('0','3','28'),('1','1','74'),('1','1','2')]


from collections import defaultdict
your_dict = defaultdict(dict)

for row in x:
    your_dict[row[0]][row[1]] = tuple([n for n in [r[2] for r in x if r[1] == row[1]]])
```

Your precise expected output:

```
{'0': {'0': ('20','25'), '3': ('28')}, '1': {'1': ('74','2')}})
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
x = [('0', '0', '20'), ('0', '0', '25'),('0', '3', '28'), ('1', '1', '74'), ('1', '1', '2')]

a = {}

def add_dict2(innerdict, ele2, ele3):
    if not innerdict.get(ele2):
        innerdict[ele2] = []

    innerdict[ele2].append(ele3)

def add_dict(elel, ele2, ele3):
    if not a.get(ele1):
        a[ele1] = {}

    add_dict2(a[ele1], ele2, ele3)

for (ele1, ele2, ele3) in x:
    add_dict(ele1, ele2, ele3)

print(a)
```

Prints

```
{'0': {'0': ['20', '25'], '3': ['28']}, '1': {'1': ['74', '2']}}
```